# Complex order algorithm of an ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi everyone i'm working in a tile-based game engine and i got a bit stuck with units movement. Overall you can think it as a Tower Defense game where units have to follow a path (brown tiles), here comes the example image:

### [image]

As you can see there are numbers in the Tiles with represent the drawing order. So when the map is initalized i take all the tiles that are of the type 1 (brown) and add them to an ArrayList.

Problem is that those ArrayList Tiles are in the drawing order. So my Units will start moving from tile 58 cause is the first tile from the drawing order.

How would you order the brown tiles starting from left (nº97) till right (nº118)?

I can think about taking the first tile that is the 97 by knowing that is the one with the lowest X position but from there what?

Comment: Your numbers do not intuitively correspond with the spatial arrangement of your grid. Therefore it is probably better if you used an x, y coordinate pair for your tile instead of some arbitrary number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're formatting your information in a strange way to solve this problem. If your units are starting at tile 58, then somewhere you're telling them to start at the first drawn tile? Optimally, if you want to have different maps, wouldn't you want to be able to define a particular point on the grid and tell them to start from there?

(Without knowing more about your code structure, it's hard to say how you'd do that.)

Once you've defined a point for them to start from and a point for them to end on, you could then use A* or D* search to define a path for the entities to take along your grid. That would also give you a lot more options in your design-- you could have the player modify the grid throughout the game and force the units to take a new path.

Comment: When I initalize the map tiles, if the tile type is 1 i make it brown and add it to an ArrayList called Path. Problem is that they are added in the render order, so my path.get(0) equals to the tile number 58. After all i wanted to prevent to use pathfinding cause it looked complex for my knowledge.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably just want to define an explicit order of brown tiles. Have some array of tile-representing integers like [97, 98, 99, ..., 118], and use that as your path.